# Shrink UIView from top

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a uiview that is overlaying and blocking interaction with my view on top of the superview. I've tried bringing the blocked view to the front but that doesn't work either.

Here's the code for the blocking view:

```
self.gesstureView = UIView(frame: screenBounds)
        if let gestureView = self.gesstureView, let controlDockView = self.controlDockView, let controlTopView = self.controlTopView {
            gestureView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleBottomMargin]
            gestureView.frame.size.height -= controlDockView.frame.height
            gestureView.contentMode = .center
            gestureView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.view.addSubview(gestureView)
```

Heres the code for the view that's blocked:

```
let topHeight = screenBounds.height * 0.15
        self.controlTopView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenBounds.width, height: topHeight))
        if let controlTopView = self.controlTopView {
            controlTopView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            controlTopView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin]
            controlTopView.addBlurEffect()
            self.view.addSubview(controlTopView)
            // does not work view is still hidden
            self.view.bringSubview(toFront: controlTopView)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you push a minimal, compiling code to GitHub with the problem?

Comment: Couple of things to try:  UIColor.clear makes your view completely invisible, make it to a different color for testing. If you want it to be translucent, use UIColor(white:, alpha:) and mess with the alpha. Have you tried to send your gesture view to the back? Have you added breakpoints to see if the view is added? By setting breakpoints after each call of view.addsubview, you can tell which views are added first and if they are ever set.

Comment: @farkasseb here is the sample code replicating the issue https://github.com/BHigh17/UIView_code

Comment: @Jazure originally the color of the view to clear that is when I discovered the bug and switched it to red to debug. I will try breakpoints and see which views are being added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the sample code!

The problem is that you add your `gestureView` to the view hierarchy after you brought `controlTopView` to front. So `controlTopView` will actually be the second view this is why it is not visible.
[image: Problem]

To solve the problem either add `controlTopView` lastly or bring it to the front after you've added everything.

```
view.addSubview(previewView)
view.addSubview(controlDockView)
view.addSubview(gestureView)
view.addSubview(controlTopView)
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Thank you for your help! Question would it be easier if I called `self.view.insertSubview(gestureView, belowSubview: controlTopView)` after I added my `gestureView` to the view hierarchy?

Comment: You can do that too, I don't think that would matter a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case -- have you checked if your `controlTopView` is not visible simply because it has nothing visible to draw? In your code snippet, the `controlTopView` only has a transparent background color and a blur effect (which wouldn't do anything to the solid red behind it).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to really see whats going on is to use the UI debugger in Xcode.  It will show you what is obscuring what.  Also, it is very likely that the UIViews are being drawn in an order you are not anticipating.

1. [image: Run your project and click on the round circle]

You should resize and select the hidden view....if its actually there.